# program throw exception that compile with visual studio but g++ is fine

Tags: c++, exception, multiple-inheritance

No more word to say, read the code below:

-------INotifier.h-----------------------

```
struct INotifier
{
    virtual void do_notifier() = 0;    
    virtual ~INotifier(void);
};
```

------------Notifier.h-----------------

```
#include "INotifier.h"
class Notifier : public virtual INotifier
{    
public:
    explicit Notifier(void);    
    virtual void do_notifier();    
    virtual ~Notifier(void);
};
```

-----ICommand.h----------------

```
#include "INotifier.h"
struct ICommand : public virtual INotifier
{
    virtual void execute(void) = 0;
    virtual ~ICommand(void);
};
```

-----DelegateCommand.h-----------

```
#include "INotifier.h"
#include "Notifier.h"
#include "ICommand.h"

class DelegateCommand
    : public virtual ICommand
    , public virtual INotifier
    , public Notifier
{
public:
    DelegateCommand()
        : INotifier()
        , ICommand()
        , Notifier()
    {
    }

    virtual void execute()
    {
    }

    virtual ~DelegateCommand(void)
    { }
};
```

------Notifier.cpp---------

```
#include "INotifier.h"
#include "Notifier.h"
#include "ICommand.h"  

Notifier::Notifier(void)
    : INotifier()
{  }
void Notifier::do_notifier()  { }

Notifier::~Notifier(void)   { }

ICommand::~ICommand(void) { }
INotifier::~INotifier(void) { }
```

-----main.cpp-----------

```
#include "DelegateCommand.h"    
int main()
{
    auto cmd = new DelegateCommand();
    return 0;
}
```

[project file](http://speedy.sh/P3DZD/inherite.zip)

throw a strange exception I never meet, I don't know how to solve it.
[image]

Comment: Please post the sample code as a single .cpp that I can paste into VS and run (merge class declarations with definitions).

Comment: runs fine for me! anyway why is DelegateCommand inheriting from INotifier and Notifier?

Comment: *Could* be in relation with virtual inheritance. As you inherit virtually, you actually only inherit a single instance of INotifier (directly and via Notifier), but you call the constructor twice (once directly, once via Notifier). Rather guessing, though, have no VS available currently.

Comment: and destructors don't take arguments so there's no need to specify `void`

Comment: Cannot reproduce either. Please build a true [mcve]...

Comment: @Prab Is that you use visual studio 2015?

Comment: @Prab `void someFunction()` and `void someFunction(void)` are equivalent. The latter is the only way to declare a function without arguments in C, C++ adopted this as legal, too, for compatibility with C.

Comment: don't mix structs and classes. Structs default to public access while classes don't

Comment: @Aconcagua yes I'm aware of that but a C compiler isn't being used here

Comment: I compile it with g++, every things is ok. but with visual studio 2015 it throw exception.

Comment: actually, these code are partially move from https://github.com/PureMVC/puremvc-cpp-multicore-framework

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code, rather there's a problem with VS2015. VS2010 and VS2012 don't exhibit it.

Comment: @Prab I referenced to your comment: 'and destructors don't take arguments so there's no need to specify `void`' - there are many people that prefer stating 'no argument' by usage of `void`, and it is absolutely legal in C++. I personally consider this ugly, and in this respect, I'm with you, but actually it's a matter of personal taste...

Comment: @RexSmith - Just to understand what's doing Visual Studio... if, in `DelegateCommand` declaration, you change the inheritance of `Notifier` from `public Notifier` to `public virtual Notifier`... you get the same error ?

Comment: @max66 yes, I get the same error.